# AngularJS1 directive with `terminal:true` will disable rendering of expressions, why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div>{{ hello }}</div>
    <div my-terminal>{{hello}}</div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
const app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.hello = 'Hello, AngularJS'
})

app.directive('myTerminal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        link: function () {
            console.log('--- myTerminal')
        }
    }
})
```

Please notice the `terminal` is `true`.

Result:

[image]

From angularjs document, I found when `terminal` is `true`, any other directives applied on the same element with lower priority will not be executed, but I can't explain why `<div my-terminal>{{hello}}</div>` will not render the expression `{{hello}}`

A small complete demo for this question: https://github.com/freewind-demos/angularjs1-directive-terminal-issue-demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Docs:

> ## terminal
>
> If set to `true` then the current `priority` will be the last set of directives which will execute (any directives at the current `priority` will still execute as the order of execution on same `priority` is undefined). **Note that expressions and other directives used in the directive's template will also be excluded from execution.**
>
> — [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - terminal](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-terminal-)

A better explaination of what that means comes from the Docs for `ng-non-bindable` which uses the `terminal` property:

> ## ngNonBindable
>
> The `ngNonBindable` directive tells AngularJS not to compile or bind the contents of the current DOM element, including directives on the element itself that have a lower priority than `ngNonBindable`. This is useful if the element contains what appears to be AngularJS directives and bindings but which should be ignored by AngularJS. This could be the case if you have a site that displays snippets of code, for instance.
>
> — [AngularJS ng-non-bindable Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)

Comment: Thanks for bringing `ngNonBindable` here, that's an excellent use case!

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js :

```
function addTextInterpolateDirective(directives, text) {
      var interpolateFn = $interpolate(text, true);
      if (interpolateFn) {
        directives.push({
          priority: 0,
          compile: function textInterpolateCompileFn(templateNode) {
            var templateNodeParent = templateNode.parent(),
                hasCompileParent = !!templateNodeParent.length;
...
```

So using expression {{}} results in adding directive. Guess thats why it is affected by 'terminate' property.

Comment: I added `priority: 0` to `myTerminal` directive, to make it and the "added" one has the same level priority, but `{{ hello }}` is still not rendered.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-terminal- Note that expressions and other directives used in the directive's template will also be excluded from execution.

Comment: Thanks, it's noted in the doc, but I ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ng-bind

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <div>{{hello}}</div>
  <div my-terminal ng-bind="hello"></div>
</div>
```

The DEMO

```js
const app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.hello = 'Hello, AngularJS'
})

app.directive('myTerminal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        link: function () {
            console.log('--- myTerminal')
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div>{{ hello }}</div>
    <div my-terminal ng-bind="hello"></div>
</body>
```